# How do I convert a string into an OctetString (C#)?

Tags: c#, ldap, attributes

I'm importing data into an LDAP store. The attribute in question is of type OctetString. I have a normal string that I need to get into that attribute.

I'm using C# (.net 3.5)

How do I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, an OctetString is just a byte array. Not to be confused with Octal (base 8)

Completely open to correction but some random googling would seem to agree...
This will convert your string to a byte array

```
byte[] octets = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("abcd");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
System.Text.Encoding utf8 = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
byte[] octets = utf8.GetBytes("Réne");
```

Answer (score 0):

An [`OctetString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684451.aspx) appears to simply be a string represented as an array of bytes (hence *octets*).

The MSDN page on [Octet String (SID) Property Type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180873(VS.80).aspx) provides the following example for writing an Octet String:

```
byte[] usrSID = (byte[])usr.Properties["objectSid"].Value;
usr.Properties["objectSid "].Clear();
usr.Properties["objectSid "].Value = usrSID;
usr.CommitChanges();
```